# Rewriting the same code getting different results

Tags: python

I am new to Python
I was trying the following problem:

> Write a program that reads an integer value n from the standard input
> and prints the result of the expression:

```
((n + 1) * n + 2) * n + 3
```

Hence I wrote the following code:

```
print(((int(input()) + 1) * int(input()) + 2) * int(input()) + 3)
```

and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "jailed_code", line 4, in <module>

    print(((int(input()) + 1) * int(input()) + 2) * int(input()) + 3)

EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

then I tried this:

```
n = int(input())

print(((n + 1) * n + 2) * n + 3)
```

and it works apparently while it seems like both of these are the same thing.

Am I making some error here and what does this error message really mean?

I am using PyCharm IDE and the problem is from [here](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/6461).

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: Is it better now? @ShivamJha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` takes vaalue from console whenever called, so instead of taking 3 `inputs()`, assign it to a `variable`:
So 2nd one works while first one do not. In first one, as you have provided 3 `inputs()`, the compiler expects 3 values to be entered and gives error when you enter one

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input())

print(((n + 1) * n + 2) * n + 3)
```

and

```
print(((int(input()) + 1) * int(input()) + 2) * int(input()) + 3)
```

are not the same thing. The second piece of code prompts the interpreter to take three inputs from the console, while the first code snippet takes only one input. But using the second line is perfectly legal in `python3` and you just have to give three inputs to the console, each followed by an `enter`, you might have got error in some other part of the code.

Comment: Yeah i got the error because the IDE was checking it as a solution to the query and hence it did not match